# Kerning in GeoServer labels?

Tags: geoserver, labeling

How can I resolve problematic kerning in GeoServer labels?

Example:

[image]

Problematic kerning is in "San Glissando"

Another example:

[image]

Geoserver documentation contains only:

```
<Font>
       <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
       <CssParameter name="font-size">12</CssParameter>
       <CssParameter name="font-style">normal</CssParameter>
       <CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</CssParameter>
</Font>
```

I would like to find something like the CSS parameters, which can change spacing between letters in labels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to control word spacing, to the best of my knowledge all you can try to do is to change the font and hope it's handled better.

If you can develop in java, it seems that there is some kerning control that GeoServer (actually, GeoTools) currently does not use, it could be turned into a vendor option, or if it's always better, be the new default:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996675/accessing-font-kerning-information-in-java2d

Comment: Follow up, in GeoServer 2.12 onwards kerning will be on by default.